# How to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in jboss eap 6.4

Tags: java, ssl, redirect, jboss

As I have already configured both HTTP and HTTPS connector in `standalone.xml` file and in HTTP connector I have used `redirect-port="8443"`.
So is there any thing I need to configure in jboss level to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

I want to configure this redirection only at jboss level(without any web.xml of application which deployed in jboss) and I am using JBOSS EAP 6.4.0

Also I want to know is there any solution to block HTTP(Only HTTPS work) for a particular application context which deployed in jboss eap 6.4.0.Only at JBOSS Config level.

**HTTP Connector**

```
 <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" 
            redirect-port="8443"/>
```

**HTTPS Connector**

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" 
           enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
    <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="XXX" password="******" 
         certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/xxx.jks" protocol="TLSv1" 
         verify-client="false"/>
</connector>
```

Any Help is great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the problem : How to stop access from http for specific application can be done through VirtualHost definition defined at JBOSS application server and bind your application to this host using jboss-web.xml.

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <virtual-host>www.mydot.com</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

Reference :

[JBOSS-AS :Chapter 7. Setting up Virtual Hosts](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch07.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to do this only at jboss config level.